# Is something that is true for one Normal distribution true for other Normal distributions with different means and standard deviations?

Tags: statistics

I am currently analyzing the findings of a Statistical study of the accuracy of point estimators (of Normal distributions). This study created samples of n = 100 with an assumed mean of 10, and standard deviation of 1 for each.

Am I incorrect in assuming that the conclusions of this study are true for all instances of a Normal distribution? To be more clear, if this study proved a point estimator to be unbiased, could I assume this point estimator to be unbiased for all Normal distributions (including the standard Normal with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please do not have signatures like "Thank you so much!"

Comment: You might want to link to the study. From this description, it's unclear what was really proved.